# Design a baseball seam so that all of its 2D surfaces are equally divided?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, spheres

Is it possible to seam a baseball so that the surface area inside the seam will always be equal to the surface area outside of the seam, from all hemispherical viewpoints?

Comment: This is possibly an interesting question, but it's not very precise; for example, what does "from some angles" mean, precisely? Is a viewpoint necessarily at infinity? I.e., are we only considering hemispheres, or all spherical caps no larger than a hemisphere?

Comment: Good point. If the spherical cap was small enough then it would be either fully inside or outside of the seam, making the requirements impossible. I'll rephrase the question to make it clear that we are considering hemispheres only.

Comment: Do you require the seam to be connected and have no self-intersections? If you drop either requirement, it's easy to produce examples.

Comment: For the former, pick any simply connected subset $X$ of the sphere with surface area $1/4$ that of the sphere which does not intersect its image $a(X)$ under the antipodal map $a$ and which has nice boundary $\partial X$ (any spherical cap of internal angle $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ should do), and declare your seam to be $\partial X \cup a(\partial X)$ (with, say, $X \cup a(X)$ the "inside"). Then, $a$ is an area-preserving bijection of the sphere to itself that maps the inside of the seam to itself and maps any hemisphere to its opposite, so exactly half of the inside is in any hemisphere.

Comment: If you drop the latter, just take $X$ to be any lune with angle $\pi / 4$ and repeat the above construction. Then, the seam $\partial X \cup \partial a(X)$ is connected, with self-intersections at the poles.

Comment: The latter example shows that even with the restriction that the curve be connected and without self-intersection one can ensure that the visible surface areas inside and outside are within an arbitrary fixed $\epsilon > 0$ from any viewpoint, by replacing the self-intersections with sufficiently small pairs of nonintersecting arcs appropriately oriented.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'm 90% sure your last comment is a valid solution. The terminology was mostly new to me, but from what I gather, the first option is to create two equal circular seams around both poles, and the second is to create two crescent shapes that connect at the poles. The third seems like the solution but I can't fully visualise it. Would an illustration be possible?

Comment: To be clear, the last suggestion does *not* give a solution, at least not without some modification: It only says that one can easily make arbitrarily good *approximate* solutions, that is, for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can design a simple, closed seam so the intersections of the hemisphere with the inside and the outside both have areas between $\pi - \epsilon$ and $\pi + \epsilon$. I don't have a drawing program handy on this computer, but you can imagine replacing both intersections $$\times$$ with appropriate pairs $$)\,($$

Comment: I guess that manufacturing defects, and the width between stitches, and the minimum width of the thread would all combine to require a certain degree of tolerance in the real world. Feel free to post it as a valid answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as the comments under the original question show, depends on the precise formulation of the problem.

Let's regard the baseball as a unit sphere $\Bbb S^2$. We then ask if there is an open subset $X \subset \Bbb S^2$ (the "inside") for all hemispheres $H \subset \Bbb S^2$ we have
$$\mu(X \cap H) = \mu((\Bbb S^2 - X) \cap H) ,$$
where $\mu$ is the standard measure on the sphere. We declare the "seam" to be $\partial X$ and the "outside" to be $Y := \Bbb S^2 - (X \cup \partial X)$, in which case we can write the above condition more symmetrically as $\mu(X \cap H) = \mu(Y \cap H)$.

The key fact is that any $X$ satisfying the condition must be invariant under the antipodal map ${\bf x} \mapsto -{\bf x}$. To see this, first note that we can just as well formulate "equally divided" to mean that [*signed measure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure) $\chi_X \mu$ satisfies
$$(\chi_X \mu)(H) = \tfrac{1}{2} \mu(H) = \pi$$ is that same for all hemispheres $H$, and a [short argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2496330/155629) shows that any such measure is invariant under the antipodal map ${\bf x} \mapsto -{\bf x}$, and in our setting that $X$ is invariant under the antipodal map. (Only mentioned in passing in the linked answer is that this can be seen quickly as a satisfying consequence of the [Funk transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funk_transform). This is sufficiently nice that I'd otherwise say more about this here, but this answer will already be long enough.)

If $X$ is invariant under the antipodal map, symmetry gives first
$$(\chi_X \mu)(H) = \tfrac{1}{2} (\chi_X \mu)(\Bbb S^2) = \tfrac{1}{2} \mu(X),$$ so we must have $\mu(X) = 2 \pi$, and then that $X$ has the desired "equally divided" property iff it has these two properties: that (a) $X$ is invariant under the antipodal map and (b) $\mu(X) = 2 \pi$.

There are infinitely many such choices of $X$. We can construct a class of cheap examples, which contains the "lune" example from the comments under the original question: Fix a set $Z$ with measure $\mu(Z) = \pi$ contained inside some hemisphere and set $X := Z \cup -Z$.

On the other hand, for the usual seam on a baseball the "inside" and "outside" are both connected, and we can ask whether this is possible for an "equally divided arrangement" as above (for the examples in the previous paragraph, the inside, $X$, is not connected). The answer is no.

If $X$ is connected, then (since it is open) it is path-connected, so for any choice $x \in X$ there is a path $\gamma$ in $X$ with endpoints $x$ and $-x$, and since $X$ is connected, $-\gamma$ is another path with endpoints $-x$ and $x$. Then the set $C := \gamma \cup -\gamma$ has the property that for any $y \not\in C$, $y$ and $-y$ are in different components of $\Bbb S^2 - C$. Then, since $\Bbb S^2 - C \supset Y$, from taking $y$ in the outside, $Y$, we conclude that $Y$ is not connected.

Finally, we can relax our requirements and ask only for approximate solutions, that is, given $\epsilon > 0$ we can ask for $X$ for which
$$|\mu(X \cap H) - \mu(Y \cap H)| < \epsilon$$ for all $H$. As described in the comments under the original question, this is possible (for all $\epsilon > 0$) even under the condition that $X, Y$ are connected.

Here's a plot of a seam defining an approximate solution satisfying the above condition for some small $\epsilon$:

[image]

Comment: Could you show a sketch or two of what the final product would look like? This would help a lot with reading through your answer for us non-mathematicians.

Comment: Of the approximate solution you mean?

Comment: Yes, the approximate solution would be fine.

Comment: Sure, I've added a plot of the approximate solution.