# Symmetries of a curve on the unit sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, symmetry

Let $\mathbb{S}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be the unit sphere. Let $\gamma : [0, l] \to \mathbb{S}^2$ be a smooth embedded closed curve. Let $\vec{\nu}$ be one of the two continuous unit normal vector field on $\gamma$ (with a little abuse, I am denoting with $\gamma$ also the image of the curve). Just to be clear, $\vec{\nu}$ is tangent to the sphere.

Let $f: \gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ be  a smooth, given function, with only a finite number of zeroes. Let assume also that the following property holds:  for every $K \in \mathcal{Kill}(\mathbb{S}^2)$
\begin{equation}\label{asd}
\int_\gamma f \langle \nu, K\rangle \, d\sigma = 0.
\end{equation}

With $\mathcal{Kill}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ I mean the Lie algebra of Killing vector fields on the sphere.

**Question**: what can I say about $\gamma$ and/or $f$?

For instance, it should be true that if $\gamma$ is a circle and $f$ is constant, then $\int_\gamma f \langle \nu, K\rangle \, d\sigma = 0$ holds for every $K \in \mathcal{Kill}(\mathbb{S}^2)$. 
Is it true the converse? I feel that the converse might not be true, but maybe it is possible to prove some weaker kind of symmetry for $\gamma$ and/or $f$?

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks for the comment and for the edit! mmh.. can you elaborate? It seems to me that it must be zero.. Let $\gamma$ be a great circle and $K$ an infinitesimal generation of a rotation of axis $L$, for some line $L$ passing through the origin. Then take $\pi$ the plane containing $L$ and perpendicular to $\gamma$. It seems to me that $\langle \nu, K \rangle $ is an "odd symmetric" function w.r.t. $\pi$. So the stuff on one side of the plane cancels out with the stuff on the other side. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, and you don't even need $\gamma$ to be a circle: for any simple closed curve $\gamma$ we have $\int_\gamma \langle \nu , K \rangle d \sigma = \int_\Omega \mathcal L_K \omega$ where $\Omega$ is the region enclosed by $\gamma$ and $\omega$ is the area form. Since $K$ is Killing we have $\mathcal L_K \omega = 0.$ (See [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485432/a-volume-form-on-the-sphere-which-gives-equal-areas-to-all-hemispheres-is-invari).)

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Ah, right! Good point!!

Comment: When $f$ is not constant, you should be able to show that the condition becomes $\int_\Omega df(K) \omega = 0$ for all $K.$ Not sure if this tells you anything about $f$ or $\gamma$; at most I think it would tell you some relationship between them.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis So with "$f$" you mean any smooth extension of $f$ on the inside of $\Omega$?

Comment: Yeah, I must, you're right.